# loginURL in web.config forms authentication within virtual directory based page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an application in a virtual directory (ASP.Net 4.0 C#). It is secured with forms authentication. Within my application are sub directories so that I have a content tree that matches the rough order of my website

www.server.com/application/sub-directory1/sub-directory2/

```
 <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="100" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
```

What should the "loginUrl" be to allow it to work from a subdirectory? i.e. if your session times out, how can you get the loginUrl to redirect you to the right place?

if you set it to loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" and you are in sub-directory 1, it redirects you to  www.server.com/application/sub-directory1/login.aspx which does not exist. I want it to always redirect to www.server.com/application/login.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure the loginUrl inside the web.config file located at the root folder? If so that should work. I have an asp.net 3.5 with a similar structure. When I timeout inside http://localhost/Providence /Member/Mail/NewMessage.aspx, I am redirected to http://localhost/Providence/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fProvidence%2fMember%2fMail%2fNewMessage.aspx.

I have not tried this with asp.net 4.0 though.

Comment: Essentially what I'm asking is what to put for the loginUrl to have it do that. Anything I do seems to always return me to http://localhost/login.aspx and it does not exist

Comment: Here is my setup and it works:
* I have a web.config file at the application root only (http://localhost/Providence). 
*Login.aspx is also located at the application root.
*Providence is a virtual directory.
`<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"   timeout="60"  name="XXXXX" >  </form>
<location path="Member">
   <system.web> <authorization>  <deny users="?" /> </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>`
As long as long as the web.config file is at the root of the website and “application” is setup up as an application in IIS, then your current configuration should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I i fixed it by removing

from appSettings section